# SupplyCategoryUnavailable - what does this FBAOutboundServiceMWS error mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

We have a script for submitting Amazon FBA orders via FBAOutboundServiceMWS, using  CreateFulfillmentOrder request.

Orders for some products cannot be placed, we are getting this error:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentOutboundShipment/2010-10-01/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>InvalidRequestException</Code>
<Message>Value SupplyCategoryUnavailable for parameter MerchantSku is invalid.</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>22dafce7-7457-4232-b994-efea4f386dca</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

There is no information about it in a documentation, and we do not see any difference between products which experience the issue and products which do not.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned, those were SKUs called SNL – small and light program with amazon.com.

Below an answer from Amazon customer support which we have received:

Please confirm with if the items meet these conditions:

- Weigh less than or equal to 8 ounces
- Have dimensions less than or equal to 9x6x2 inches
- Priced under $10

If the above mentioned conditions are met you have to do it manually